# I can't make a Toolbar appear to be floating

Tags: android, android-layout

Good morning, I am using Android Studio and trying to make a Toolbar have a shading at the bottom with elevation, to make it look like it is floating, however this does not work, no shading is shown.

Some details:

- I use Pixel 3A for the simulation, it has API 34.
- Version 1.9.0 of Android material

Código de activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/shadowView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3.5dp"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I tried creating shape, using styles, setting clipchildren: false, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to show the shadow i can say.

In your current code you have the background of the toolbar as black color, so you can add some gray color to the view which you have below the toolbar. like below code.,

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/shadowView"
        android:background="#707070"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3.5dp"/>
```

this will show gray shadow below the toolbar.

Or the other way around you can add elevation to your AppBarLayout itself, it will show shadow automatically. But the black background on toolbar is not making it visible. Like below.,

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:elevation="8dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


</FrameLayout>
```

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

I have checked the above code, check once from your side.

Comment: It does not work for me, maybe it is API version 34?

Comment: I tried API 33 and 31 and it still doesn't work

Comment: Its not because of the API version. Have you tried adding elevation to the AppBarLayout ??

Comment: Yes I tried, from what I was reading, in the latest versions of the dependencies that Android uses, they removed that option, the one with the shadow under the toolbars....